# @Transactional on @Async methods in Spring Boot with shared object

Tags: java, spring, oracle, multithreading, hibernate

I have a requirement where I have to save a lot of data into an Oracle DB.

I want to use multithreading to speed things up. Everything is in a transaction.

I have two tables in a many to one relation.

First, I synchronously save the one-side entity with repo.save()

Next I build batches of 25 many-side entity entries (from an initial list of a few hundred) and start a new thread using @Async to save them.
Each of this entities has to reference the one-side entity so I pass the new one-side entity created previously to the @Async methods.
I wait for all of them to complete before exiting.

Problem is I get the following exception :

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER.ENTITY_FK1) violated - parent key not found
```

Which basically means that the one-side entity I am trying to reference from the many-side does not exist.

From here the transaction fails and everything gets rolled back.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Update with code :

In OrchestratorService.class :

```
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
  public void importDataFromFile(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    MyDto myDto = convertor.convertFileToDto(file);
    log.info("myDto : {}", myDto.toString());

    ParentEntity savedParent = parentEntityService.saveParent(myDto.getFileName());
    
    childService.saveAllChildren(savedParent, myDto);

  }
```

ParentEntityService.class :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ParentEntity saveParent(String fileName){
    ParentEntity parentEntity= ParentEntity.builder()
            .fileName(fileName)
            .loadingDate(LocalDate.now())
            .build();

    ParentEntity savedParentEntity = parentEntityRepository.save(parentEntity);

    log.info("Saved ParentEntity : {} ", savedParentEntity );

    return savedPpassImportCtrlEntity;
}
```

ChildService.class :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void saveAllChildren(ParentEntity parentEntity, MyDto myDto) throws Exception{

    List<CompletableFuture<ProcessStatus>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<ChildrenData>> lists = ListUtils.partition(myDto.getChildrenDataList(), 25);

    for (List<ChildrenData> list :lists) {
      CompletableFuture<ProcessStatus> result = asyncSaveBatchService.saveBatch(parentEntity, list);
      completableFutures.add(result);
    }

    // wait for all to finish
    CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    combinedFuture.get();

    for(CompletableFuture<ProcessStatus> result : completableFutures){
      if(result.get().getStatus().equals(Boolean.FALSE)){
        throw new RuntimeException("Process failed : \n " + result.get().getErrorMessage());
      }
    }
}
```

And finally AsyncSaveBatchService.class :

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<ProcessStatus> saveBatch(ParentEntity parentEntity, List<ChildrenData> list){

    try{
        List<ChildrenEntity> childrenEntitiesToSave = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ChildrenData childrenData: list) {

            ChildrenEntity childrenEntity = ChildrenEntity .builder()
                    .firstName(childrenData.getFirstName())
                    .lastName(childrenData.getLastName())
                    .parent(parentEntity)
                    .build();

            childrenEntitiesToSave.add(childrenEntity);

        }

        childrenEntityRepository.saveAll(childrenEntitiesToSave);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ProcessStatus.builder().status(Boolean.TRUE).errorMessage(null).build());
    }catch (Exception ex){
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ProcessStatus.builder().status(Boolean.FALSE).errorMessage(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex)).build());
    }
```

Comment: If you need to insert large amounts of data, JdbcTemplate with [batchUpdate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-advanced-jdbc) would be a better option than hibernate

Comment: SQL*Loader or *external tables* would be even better option that JdbcTemplate to load large data. But in any case you must care about the *order* of the load - your problem is that a *parent* row does not exists while you are storing the *child*.

Comment: Could u please put your component/code here? I wonder if you are using @Transactional in Asyn as well? One more question, couldn't you commit your one-side entity before starting pushing batch/async part? It looks like your async transaction is different than one-side so that is why oracle doesn't see that values which inserted before, it rollbacks one-side where many-side/batch not processed probably at all

Comment: @indybee I am inserting data, not updating, is there also a batch insert option in jdbc ?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I managed to save the parent before the child, thank u for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I wanted to do multiple calls to Async methods (for each batch) and, if one of them fails, the transaction on everything else does not rollback because each Async uses one thread.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I added the code (modified for company privacy reasons)

Comment: batchUpdate can be used to insert also, [some examples](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/)

Comment: Use sql loader. It will be faster than any other option. Including multithreading.